# Querying only one row from a one to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a products table and a product_pictures table, where a single product can have many pictures (one to many relationship). I am trying to display all of the product with all of its details (such as name, quantity, etc.) and only one of its product picture. This is what i have tried so far.

```
$products = Product::->join('product_pictures', 'products.product_id', '=', 'product_pictures.product_id')
        ->select('product_name', 'quantity', 'products.product_id', 'product_picture_id')
        ->groupBy('products.product_id')
        ->get();
```

I have also tried to use `distinct` to no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: The facts if you use `get()` you will get all the entries that match the query... if you use `first()` you will get only one entry (the first one) that matches your query. When you list out the products you could use this: $product->product_pictures()->first(); But you need to setup the relationship in your Product model

Comment: I think `hasOne` relationship between products and pictures could solve your problem..

Comment: @lewis4u if we use $product->product_pictures()->first() 
we need to add foreach of products and then we can access product's image.
It'll run many queries  for ex. If I have 15 products it'll run 16 queries (1 for getting all products and 15 for getting products image.) so batter to use row query while we are dealing with such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `with` function. It will include a model's relation. So if you have a `Product` model, you can query `Product`'s relationship .e.g `Product` -> `ProductPicture`.

Make sure you have the relationship set up in your Models. It would roughly be like this:

`Product` model:

```
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPicture', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

`ProductPicture` model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

The query with `with` function will look like:

```
$products = Product::with(['pictures' => function($q) {
    $q->take(1);
])->get();
```

It will get all products, and attach a picture (its relationsip) to that product.

**Update**:
It turns out it will only get 1 picture from a product, and leave the other products' pictures empty. So the `take` function nested in a `with` will only work as expected if you're fetching a single parent using `find`.

What you can try is to define a new function in the `Product` model like so, it will only attach a single picture to the product:

```
public function singlePicture()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPicture', 'product_id', 'id')->limit(1);
}
```

Call it in the query:

```
$products = Product::with(['singlePicture'])->get();
```

Comment: I just gotten around to trying your answer. For some reason, it only fetch the first picture for the first product. The rest of the product 'picture' array is empty, even though their picture in the database exists. I tried changing the ```->take(1)``` to the corresponding number of product that im fetching, and it works for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you attach the output you have? And the expected output. A sample of 2-3 array elements is fine.

Comment: Hold on, I'll check it out. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: I am suspicious there is something wrong on my side because it still wont work. Even though i check in the database there indeed pictures for every one if my products. it would still only give the first picture for the first product. The only way around that i can do is to fetch the total amount of products i am fetching, putting it in a variable and put that variable in the ```take()``` from your first answer

Comment: i don't think this works for eager loading in Laravel 9
but without eager loading it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT() function of mysql
You can also get list of all picture using single query like

```
DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(`product_picture_id` SEPARATOR ',') as product_picture_ids")
```

```
$products = Product::join('product_pictures', 'products.product_id', '=', 'product_pictures.product_id')
        ->select('product_name', 'quantity', 'products.product_id', DB::raw(" GROUP_CONCAT(`product_picture_id` SEPARATOR ',') as product_picture_ids"))
        ->groupBy('products.product_id')
        ->get();
```

Here you want to get only single field of product_picture_id, if you want multiple fields in single query, like children in json,
You can refer
https://romik-mk.medium.com/laravel-one-to-many-relation-in-single-query-5587697c259

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Product::join('product_pictures as pp', 'products.product_id', '=', 'pp.product_id')
    ->select('products.product_name', 'products.quantity', 'products.product_id', 'pp.product_picture_url')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

You need to groupBy **products.id** instead of **product_id**. It'll return only products which has product image with first product image.
If you want products that haven't single product image you can use **leftJoin**

Hope this will work!!